# error message"system cannot..."

Tags: lastools

After several intents to reinstall everything (even qgis3.8.2 zanzibar), and verify the path (several times) for the lasstools plugin, still cannot use it, as consequence of the error message *the system cannot find the specified path*. I did doble check the path in my laptop, but still nothing works. Here is the error notice from the console:

```
QGIS version: 3.8.2-Zanzibar
QGIS code revision: 4470baa1a3
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'lasground' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS' : '', 'BY_FLIGHTLINE' : False, 'CPU64' : False, 'GRANULARITY' : 1, 'GUI' : False, 'HORIZONTAL_FEET' : False, 'IGNORE_CLASS1' : 0, 'INPUT_LASLAZ' : 'C:\\lidar\\lazlid\\700515NW.las', 'NO_BULGE' : False, 'OUTPUT_LASLAZ' : 'C:/lidar/lazlid/70015.las', 'TERRAIN' : 4, 'VERBOSE' : True, 'VERTICAL_FEET' : False }

LAStools command line
C:/LAStools\bin\lasground -v -i "C:\lidar\lazlid\700515NW.las" -city -o "C:/lidar/lazlid/70015.las"
LAStools console output
The system cannot find the path specified. 

Execution completed in 0.07 seconds
Results:
{'': None}
```

Any guess?

Comment: I take it you can set the path where lastools resides?   Try using backslashes only, I don't think `C:/` is valid

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I am looking for set the path, noticing for your comment this think about the backslashes. I realize that something is wrong there, because the QGIS set the path for default. I am trying once and again, to see the consistency in the program path. I will let you guys know what happened with this. Thanks again, I am into it...

Comment: The program is using C:/ LAStools for default.  I was trying to change it, but always back to this one.  Somebody knows other way to change the path?  I am using Properties toolbox ->Providers, as recommend by Isenburg

Comment: The lastool folder maybe within another folder i.e. C:/LAStools/LAStools

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem because i unzipped the file creating a folder with the same name. Inside "C:/LAStools" you can find another folder with the same name? In QGIS configuration for the LAStools path you must put "C:/LAStools/LAStools"